# Split dataframe into minimum n observation and do it for all rows in R

Tags: r

I have a question about dividing the dataset into several rows by function that we can set the number of minimal observations should contain in it.

Let say I have a data frame df with 8 observation:

```
df <- tibble(x = sort(sample(10:90, 8)), y = c("N","M", "N", "M", "N", "N", "M", "M"))

# A tibble: 8 x 2
      x y    
  <int> <chr>
1    13 N    
2    14 M    
3    15 N    
4    43 M    
5    49 N    
6    55 N    
7    56 M    
8    74 M
```

I want to split it with n values, let say I want the `n=3`, the output must be a data frame with the minimal number of 3 rows and the other should 5. Next, it iterates, and appends by one row and stops until it finds the number of observations of both less than 3. I want to save this data frame in a separate df. Let say df_3 and dfo_5, df_4 and dfo_4

It maybe sounds confusing I will put the example of output that I suggested, let say I want the `n=3`

```
# rows df_3
      x y    
  <int> <chr>
1    13 N    
2    14 M    
3    15 N  

# dfo_5 = the remain df have 5 rows
      x y    
  <int> <chr>
1    43 M    
2    49 N    
3    55 N    
4    56 M    
5    74 M
```

```
# rows df_4
      x y    
  <int> <chr>
1    13 N    
2    14 M    
3    15 N    
4    43 M  

# dfo_4 = the remain df have 4 rows
      x y    
  <int> <chr>
1    49 N    
2    55 N    
3    56 M    
4    74 M
```

```
# 
# 
# rows df_6 is 6 ( i will not save this)
      x y    
  <int> <chr>
1    13 N    
2    14 M    
3    15 N    
4    43 M    
5    49 N    
6    55 N   

# because the remainder df contains less 3 rows
      x y    
  <int> <chr>
1    56 M    
2    74 M
```

From these df's I want to apply the proportion of M and N respectively

```
function (df,n){
for df split into n
to be df1 and df2
if nrow in df1 and df2 < 3
then stop

}

apply proportion M for df1
apply proportion M for df2
```

A help will be much appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but couldn't you just split your original data frame into 2 data frames, where the second is n-1 rows? Why do you need to include a loop or iteratively evaluate different data frame splits?

Answer (score 0):

```
  data <- tibble(x = sort(sample(10:90, 8)), y = c("N","M", "N", "M", "N", "N", "M", "M"))
  m = 3; n = 3
  while((nrow(data) - m) > n){
  assign(paste("df_", m, sep = ""), data[1:m,]) 
  assign(paste("df0_", (nrow(data)-m), sep = ""), data[(m+1):nrow(data),])
  m = m+1
  print(m)
  }

 ls()
 #[1] "data"  "df_3"  "df_4"  "df0_4" "df0_5" "m"     "n"
```

Change value of m and n as per your requirement. For instance m =2, n=2 if you want to start with 2 rows

Comment: When I run the code, I only got value 4 and 5, what I need is a dataframe of the split.

Comment: You got split dataframes. :) As  you can see the ls() gives "df_3" , "df_4",  "df0_4" ,"df0_5" for n =3, m = 3. Above code prints the value of m in each iteration. so 4 & 5 are just value of m but if you check your workspace you will have df_3, df_4, df0_4, df0_5. You can access these split data frames.